# How to get Typescript Type definition for generating angular forms

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I am using @graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular for generating types and services for my Angular Application. Now I would like to try to generate angular forms out of this generated code.

I would like to use the LoginUserMutationMutationVariables type to generate my form, but I don't find any way to dynamically get the type definition for further processing. Something like a JSON which I then can use to generate my form.

```
export type LoginUserMutationMutationVariables = Exact<{
   email: Scalars['String'];
   password: Scalars['String'];
}>;
```

So that's one example type. I want to get for example a JSON with the types 'value' to parse it.